# Is there any better way (than by variable) to find if loop block was executed (even once)?

Tags: python, for-loop

I know that python has `else` loop feature:

```
for item in items:
    # loop block
else:
    # will execute if there is no exception or break in loop block
```

And because of that feature I wonder if there is any other smart things about loops in python. And for now I want to find a better way (than by variable) to find if loop block was executed (even once):

```
items = []
for item in items:
    # loop block

if #loop block was executed:
    print("Big brother is watching you!")
```

Comment: Could you give some context; what's the problem you're trying to solve solve with this?

Comment: For list-type objects you could just check `if items:` after the loop, but this won't work if `items` is e.g. a generator.

Comment: What is wrong with setting a flag inside the loop like `ran_loop = True`?

Comment: @tobias_k For generators, use `inspect.getgeneratorstate()`, but I don't think the OP is asking about generators

Comment: @Chris_Rands Interesting, but that does not seem to show any difference for a consumed empty or non-empty generator. And yes, OP might not be concerned with generators at all, just wanted to point out.

Comment: don't you love those "fundamental" questions?

Comment: @chris-rands I think it's very pythonic to use some extra cool features. For example - what is wrong with range() and a[i]? Nothing. But we have _enumerate_ and by the way it is shorter.

Comment: @tobias_k How do you mean? You get `GEN_CLOSED` for a consumed generator

Comment: @egvo Setting a flag seems Pythonic and short, but what's your actual use case?

Comment: @jonrsharpe @chris-rands Actually I'm iterating over pymongo cursor. I've found answer for it myself accidentally but question is still curious.
For pymongo cursor it will be `cursor.retrieved` attribute.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, I'm also getting `GEN_CLOSED`, but I get that for both empty and non-empty generators, so I can not use it to discriminate whether the loop body has been executed or not.

Comment: @tobias_k Ah, i understand now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `item` isn't defined anywhere else, you could just check if `item` has been assigned:

```
items = []
for item in items:
    pass
try:
    del item
except NameError:
    print("loop wasn't executed")
else:
    print("loop was executed")
```

so if `items` is empty, the loop isn't executed, so `item` isn't defined and you get the exception.

The `del item` call ensures that `item` doesn't exist when you execute this code a second time.

(ok not using another variable, but it's still overcomplex :))

Comment: Good answer, but it is more complex than using variable.

Comment: @egvo: I fully agree but you asked for it :)

Comment: it will not raise an error if the variable has been used previously, by the way. But your answer has led me to another solution - to check variable in locals(). I don't know if it is any faster (I doubt that really) and it has one more problem - string name of var will not satisfy to global renaming.

Answer (score 1):

```
items = []
for item in items:
    # loop block

if items:
    print("Big brother is watching you!")
```

Comment: Works for lists, but not for (empty) generators.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat magical approach:

```
emptysentinel = item = object()
for item in items:
    # loop block

if item is not emptysentinel:
    print("Big brother is watching you!")
```

This approach provides exactly two benefits:

1. It avoids adding *any* per loop overhead (same as [Jean-François Fabre's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44133332/364696))
2. The cost of checking if any loops occurred at the end is the second cheapest conditional check in the language (the only thing cheaper is direct truthiness testing of a variable with the value `True`, `False`, or `None`; this is one bytecode that performs a direct C pointer comparison and stores `True` or `False`, then the same direct truthiness testing) (similar to the cost of [Jean-François Fabre's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44133332/364696) when `items` is non-empty, and *much* cheaper when it's empty)

The downside is that it:

1. Requires creation of a new object to use as the sentinel (not a huge deal; plain `object` is very low overhead, using only 16 bytes of memory, with negligible CPU time)
2. Is kinda magical (using sentinels this way isn't "the obvious way to do it")

Personally, I'd stick with the flagged loop:

```
empty = True
for item in items:
    empty = False
    # loop block

if not empty:
    print("Big brother is watching you!")
```

Yes, it has to store `False` over and over, but (at least on CPython 3, as long as you're in function scope), this is just a couple of incredibly cheap bytecodes:

1. `LOAD_CONST` (a C level array lookup operation to pull `False` out of the function's constants)
2. `STORE_FAST` (a C level array store operation to shove the just loaded value into the frame's array slot assigned to the `empty` variable)

As long as you're doing any real work in the loop, the cost of an extra `LOAD_CONST`/`STORE_FAST` is pretty meaningless; on my machine, it adds 12-13 nanoseconds to the cost of each loop. The overhead of something as simple as creating the `emptysentinel` object in the first place is around 90 ns; in simple microbenchmarks, the `emptysentinel`-based approach doesn't pull ahead of the `empty`-flag-based approach until `items` contains at least 25 elements (you could pull ahead as early as eight elements if you change the sentinel creation to `emptysentinel = item = []` which avoids loading a global and constructing through general function call mechanisms, but using an empty `list` for a sentinel makes the intent even less obvious).

If the common case is that `items` is non-empty, a slightly modified (for style/minimally targeted `try` blocks) version of [Jean-François Fabre's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44133332/364696) is the fastest:

```
for item in items:
    pass

try:
    del item
except NameError:
    pass
else:
    # Everything but the del should go here, not the try block, so you don't
    # accidentally catch NameErrors from other sources
    print("Big brother is watching you!")
```

It doesn't need to initialize a sentinel or a flag, and a `try` block that doesn't raise an exception is incredibly cheap (when `items` is a `tuple` of one element, it's a tiny bit faster than the flag approach, and gets faster as `items` gets larger; it's also faster than the sentinel approach when `items` is non-empty, but it's a matter of fixed overhead; the cost per additional item is obviously the same).

Problem is, it's *much* more expensive when `items` turns out to be empty. A microbenchmark of each approach (with the `print` and `# loop block` replaced with `pass`) has the costs for an empty `items` as:

1. Flag based: 64.8 ns
2. Sentinel based: 159 ns (87.6 if `emptysentinel` is created with `[]` instead of `object()`)
3. `try`/`except`/`else` based: 661 ns

So the final rules for which approach to use that I'll give you are:

1. **Use the flags based approach**
2. Seriously, use the flags based approach; it's the fastest if `items` is empty a non-trivial amount of the time, and not too long when non-empty, and more importantly, it's *obvious*
3. Really? Okay then: If your non-empty inputs are largish and you really need the speed, but empty inputs are still semi-common, use the sentinel based approach; it scales as well as the `try`/`except`, and handles empty inputs without slowing down pathologically
4. If your inputs are almost always non-empty, you can use the `try`/`except`/`else` approach, which is consistently the fastest for non-empty `items`, at the cost of paying the overhead of a 75 long loop whenever `items` turns out to be empty.

---

Side-note: Another relatively obvious approach (equivalent to flags in obviousness to me) would be to use `enumerate`; this is more useful if you want to know how *many* items there were, not just yes/no "were there items?", but it's not terrible:

```
numitems = 0
for numitems, item in enumerate(items, 1):
    # loop block

if numitems:
    print("Big brother is watching you!")
```

Downside is that it's slower than all the other approaches, in every scenario but one;  it's faster than `try`/`except`/`else` when `items` is empty. It has higher per loop overhead than the flags based approach, and higher fixed overhead than all other options. So it's obvious, but so is the flags based approach, and flags are faster, so just use them.

Comment: clever solution with enumerate!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to check a loop variable in locals():

```
for item in items:
    # loop block

# loop block was executed
if 'item' in locals():
    print("Big brother is watching you!")
```

It has some limitations though:

1. If you had your variable defined before loop, condition will be met.
2. If you'll use global renaming of that variable, string representation of variable name will not satisfy the search term.